# Proxy button for asp:Button and anchor with target blank - solution for file download?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, download, proxy-classes

I have a

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Something" ID="btnFoo" OnClick="OnFoo" />
```

In the OnFoo event handler, I want to make a normal postback on the server (update database and rerender the UI) and at the same time I want to **download a PDF file**. There are problems when I send it like a Response (with headers, flushed etc.), because after it the page does not behave normally anymore.

So I thought myself (because I have never do that), that I could make a `proxy button`, where the javascript OnClick could click on both - the `btnFoo` and the `<a href="download.aspx?p=123" target='_blank' />`. (or window.open). In the download.aspx would be the file downloaded.

What do you think about it and what do you recommend, please?

Comment: IMHO, opening another window tab is a messy. What problem do you face with writing the file to the response?

Comment: the page has to update the DB and re-render everything on the page inclusive new scripts from asp:ScriptManager. And the page does not work correctly if I write it to the response.